# How to use vlookup or index/match to return a formula instead of a value?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm trying to use vloookup or index/match in Google sheets to pull and plug in a query formula, rather than just its resulting value.

**For example, I'm trying to use this vlookup formula:**

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A100,'SMS VLOOKUP'!A2:$B$500,2,0),""))`

**to plug in the formula:**
`=QUERY(courtdates,"SELECT D, C, BO, H WHERE BO = date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)`

Comment: Where do you need the result of `VLOOKUP`? Make and share a sample sheet with what you already have and what you need (entered manually).

Comment: Thanks for responding. I need the result of vlookup to be on a separate page. Not able to send sample sheet now.  Basically, instead of vlookup pulling a value, I want it to pull and plug in a query formula.

Comment: I still do not understand what "pull and plug in a query formula" means. Total mystery, not joking

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to take formula from one place using vlookup and then use it in other place? Something like eval or evaluate() ?

The first part is possible using FORMULATEXT(cell) but you can't convert text of the formula into actual formula. Nothing like this using formulas.

The only way is using a script.